# Possibility to add parameters in button xml?

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I currently have an activity with some buttons.

In my xml, buttons are defined like this:

```
    <ImageButton (...) android:onClick="GoToPageX"/>
```

and I have in my activity:

```
public void GotoPageX() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, PageX.class));
    finish();

}
```

The problem is that I have hundreds of buttons and do not want to write

```
<ImageButton (...) android:onClick="GoToPage1"/>
<ImageButton (...) android:onClick="GoToPage2"/>
<ImageButton (...) android:onClick="GoToPage3"/>
...
<ImageButton (...) android:onClick="GoToPage100"/>
```

and all the scripts.

I am now using

```
public void GotoPage( int i) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), activities.get(i)));
    finish();
}
```

and would like to give the parameter i from the xml, is that possible?

Thank a lot for any help.

Comment: You have hundreds of buttons in your XML? Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish, exactly? There is surely a better way. It seems like you could simply have a ListView or GridView with an adapter set to something like an array of PageButton items (e.g. containing: int page, int drawableId).

Comment: Hundreds in one layout was maybe an exageration from my side. In fact, I have 4 buttons in each activity leading to different pages (like a book but kinda different) Answer of OcuS is perfect for me.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

It is not directly possible. However, maybe you could use `android:tag` to get your parameter.

```
<ImageButton (...) android:onClick="goToPage" android:tag="25"/>

public void goToPage(View v) {
    String pageNumber = v.getTag().toString(); 
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: String pageNumber = v.getTag().toString();

Answer (score 3):

You could also do this by enabling data binding and using a lambda expression for the `onClick` value. This way is especially useful if you plan to use multiple inputs of different types. Here's an example of a simple **MainActivity.xml** in which this strategy is used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="main" type="com.example.android.myapp.MainActivity" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageButton (...) android:onClick='@{() -> main.GotoPage(1,"one")}'/>
        <ImageButton (...) android:onClick='@{() -> main.GotoPage(2,"two")}'/>
        <ImageButton (...) android:onClick='@{() -> main.GotoPage(3,"three")}'/>
        ...
        <ImageButton (...) android:onClick='@{() -> main.GotoPage(100,"one hundred")}'/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

and in **MainActivity.java**

```
public void GotoPage(int i, String otherVariable) {
    /** code using i and otherVariable **/
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** For those who don't know how to set up data binding, I will explain it here so you don't have to google around for it. First, enable `dataBinding` in the **build.gradle** file:

```
android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    ...
}
```

Also, make sure `jcenter()` is in your repositories.

Then, go to the XML of the layout where `onClick` will be used and wrap its layout in a `layout` tag with a `data` section like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable name="main" type="com.example.android.yourapp.MainActivity" />
    </data>
    <YourLayout>
        ...
    </YourLayout>
</layout>
```

For the `variable` tag's `type` parameter, you need to put the class that will contain the function which `onClick` points to. In this example, I will use the main activity class, which is named `MainActivity` in my test project.

After you have your layout wrapped in a `layout` tag like in the example above, clean the project in Android Studio. You may also need to invalidate cache/restart or close and reopen Android Studio.

Next, if the the layout with `onClick` you are trying to set up data binding for is the same layout set by `setContentView` in your main activity class, open the file that contains your main activity class. If the layout with `onClick` you are trying to set up data binding for is inflated programmatically in a different file, open the file in which the layout is inflated instead.

Add these imports to that file:

```
import com.example.android.yourapp.databinding.YourLayoutBinding;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
```

That first class you are importing is generated when you clean the project (and possibly have to invalidate cache/restart) and is automatically named after the XML file you added the `layout` wrapper to. If the layout file is named **your_layout.xml**, the import class will be named `YourLayoutBinding`. The exact import path will depend on your app name and structure, but it will always be within a `databinding` parent class.

The next step depends on whether the layout you are adding data binding to is set with `setContentView` or is inflated with `inflate`. Both versions of the following step make use of the method `setMain`. The `setMain` method is automatically generated and named using the value of the `name` parameter in the `layout` wrapper we added. Since we put `name="main"`, the method is called `setMain`.

---

**If the layout you are adding data binding to is the same layout set by `setContentView`** find the line in your main activity class that looks like `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);` and change it to use `DataBindingUtil.setContentView` instead of `setContentView`, adding `this` as its first argument. Use `binding.setMain` to point the layout's `main` variable to the current activity.

```
YourLayoutBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.your_layout);
binding.setMain(this);
```

---

**If the layout you are adding data binding to is not set by `setContentView` but rather inflated** go to where it is inflated in your code. It should look something like this:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
```

Modify it to use `DataBindingUtil.inflate`, adding the previous inflater as its first argument. Use `binding.setMain` to point the layout's `main` variable to the main activity, and use `binding.getRoot()` to get the view. It should end up like this:

```
YourLayoutBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
binding.setMain((MainActivity) getActivity());
return binding.getRoot();
```

---

Now the data binding is ready to use. Add a function for `onClick` to point to within your main activity class.

```
public void exampleFunction(int number, String text) {
    System.out.println("Number: " + number + ", Text: " + text);
}
```

You can call it from the layout you added data binding to using a lambda expression. This example function doesn't require a `View`, so it can be used like this:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/buttonID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:text="Test"
    android:onClick='@{() -> main.exampleFunction(123, "test")}'/>
```

Make sure to use single quotes around the value for `onClick` if you plan on using a `String` input.

If you do need to pass the button's view to your function, simply add a `View` parameter to your function's required arguments and use a lambda expression like this instead:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/buttonID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:text="Test"
    android:onClick='@{(view) -> main.exampleFunction(view, 123, "test")}'/>
```

Comment: `DataBinding` is verbose.

Answer (score 2):

If you will create some layout element in xml you can use there

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/some_id_value" />
```

where `some_id_value` is kind of unique string which will be translate into id which is kept in R.java (better for you- don't change anything there) than in code you can get that id by using

```
R.id.some_id_value
```

read a little bit [there](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#attributes) that's really basics.

Answer (score 1):

You can set Tags for a view. Tags are basically a way for views to have memories.

**xml:**

```
<ImageButton
    ...Other Parameters...
    android:id="@+id/Button2"
    android:tag="2"
    android:onClick="GoToPageX"/>
<ImageButton
    ...Other Parameters...
    android:id="@+id/Button3"
    android:tag="3"
    android:onClick="GoToPageX"/>
```

The line `android:tag="2"` set a tag value of `2`(string data type) to `Button2`

**Java file:**

***General Case:***
Inside `GoToPageX(View v)` function,
use `v.getTag()` to get the tag value of corresponding view(From which ever view the method was called).

***Your case:***
Add the method as follows

```
public void GoToPageX(View v){
    int i = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag()); //parseInt converts string to integer
    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), activities.get(i)));
    finish();
}
```